# Is it possible to connect to a device using its hostname?

Tags: linux, networking, hostname

I am creating a small device running Linux with a web server on it. I want it to be plug and play, connect to a network and access to it using an abstract name.

Is it possible to access to a device using only its hostname?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On some networks – yes. But on your everyday TCP/IP network, the hostname *must* be translatable to an IP address, otherwise clients will not know what to connect to.

There are several existing protocols for local name lookup, though:

- Windows traditionally used to use **NetBIOS name services** for resolving hostnames of other computers in the same LAN using UDP broadcasts. Your server will need to run the **`nmbd`** component of Samba to be discoverable using NetBIOS.

  (2023: NetBIOS was on its way out in 2013 and is now generally considered thoroughly obsolete.)

  Recent Windows versions also support **LLMNR**, which is similar to mDNS but has fewer features and requires IPv6. On Linux, **`systemd-resolved`** will have a LLMNR client. No idea about other operating systems. Probably not worth considering.

  (2023: LLMNR is already on its way out, superseded by mDNS even on Windows.)

  The latest releases of Windows 10 also support mDNS.
- OS X uses **mDNS** ("multicast DNS"), sometimes known as Bonjour, for the same purposes. (Note that mDNS generally does not resolve bare hostnames like NetBIOS would; instead, it is limited to the `.local` domain.) For mDNS, your server will need **`avahi-daemon`**.

  Newer Windows 10.19xx have mDNS support built in (but disabled). Older Windows can resolve mDNS names if Bonjour is installed (typically as part of iTunes), and OS X should support NetBIOS if "Windows file sharing" or a similar service is enabled.

  (2023: Windows now has mDNS available by default.)
- Desktop-oriented Linux systems often come with both NetBIOS and mDNS resolvers preconfigured. (That is, they run both `nmbd` and `avahi-daemon`, plus the relevant glibc NSS modules in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.)

  (2023: Nothing does NetBIOS by default anymore, only sometimes mDNS and/or LLMNR.)
- Finally, most "home routers" maintain a **local DNS domain** (`.lan`, `.home`, &c.) according to hostnames they receive **from DHCP requests** sent by computers in the LAN. Depending on what your server uses, `dhcpcd` needs the "`hostname`" option, while `dhclient` uses "`send host-name = gethostname()`".

  (2023: Hasn't changed a bit.)